# Accessing Helpers in Heroku Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console, helper

In order to track activity in my application, I built a set of helpers which take in arrays of data and spit out .csv files. I want to use these from the console like so:

```
helper.export_data(array_of_data)
```

This works fine on my machine, but the heroku console doesn't seem to let me call helper functions. I receive the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `helper' for main:Object
```

Comment: Not quite an answer to why heroku console is saying that, but in general you can't [write to the filesystem at Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). You can write to tmp and log briefly.

Comment: I figured that out, though I'd still like to be able to use helpers to flexibly arrange data to then copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess here that your application is doing some sort of initialisation to get `helper` loaded into your console, and that that initialisation isn't occurring when you spin up a Heroku console.

Is there anything that you have done in your code which initialises this `helper` object?

Comment: How would one make sure this initialization happens?

Comment: I'm running the default 'rails c' command, not sure what that initialized by default or how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Had same question, and found the answer here:
http://www.funonrails.com/2011/03/accessing-view-helpers-routes-in-rails.html

relevant part is:

```
>> include ActionView::Helpers 
>> => Object 
>> include ApplicationHelper 
>> => Object 
>> include ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper^C 
>> display_amount 2500 => "$2,500"
```